# NotifyIcon Windows 10 works on Debug but not on Publish

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-10

I stumble upon a weird bug on my desktop application, written in c#, NET 4.5, using Windows Form. I've implemented a simple NotifyIcon system that listen a specific list and, for every item added, it display the title and the description. Pretty straight forward.

It works like a charm during the Debug process, but when I publish the application no notification is shown for whatever reason. Am I missing some particular permission on Windows10?

This is the code of the EventHandler

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private void OnLogItemAdded(object sender, Utilities.ItemAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        Event e = (Event)args.item;
        switch (e.eventType)
        {
            case EventType.Info:
                MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                break;
            case EventType.Error:
                MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                break;
            case EventType.Warning:
                MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
                break;
            default:
                MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                break;
        }
        MainNotifyIcon.Visible = true;
        MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = e.Title;
        MainNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = e.Description;
        MainNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
    }
```

That's it, no other code is involved.

Based on the comment the notification icon should be explicitly set. I did it but still no results. Icon is a resource icon included in the project

```
MainNotifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;
```

Comment: How do you initialize the NotifyIcon?
Is it possible that published application doesn't find it's icon-file and therefore doesn't show the the NotifyIcon at all?

Comment: @Michael how should I initialize the notify icon? never had this issue with windows 8.

Comment: What does "publish" do?  Are you actually running this on another machine?  Did you try another?  There is a registry hack around that disabled balloon tips.  Use Regedit.exe and look at the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced key, EnableBalloonTips value.  And of course there *is* other code involved, somebody calls this OnLogItemAdded() method.  Using try/catch to swallow exceptions in loggers is too common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launch icon created by the .NET publisher creates some kind of shortcut (called an Application Reference) in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PUBLISHER\YOUR APP

The notifications don't work when you launch the application using this reference. Not sure why (bug?) but the issue is gone when you launch it using the .exe, you can probably find it somewhere here:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ID\ID\ID\YOUR APP.exe

Comment: Hi, I've same problem, have you any news about that?

Comment: I recommend to use the InstallShield Express plugin for Visual Studio instead of the default publisher to create the installer. It installs your application in de correct program files directory and uses a normal shortcut to your executable (which is the workaround for this issue).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue that didn't work in Debug mode either.

If you don't compile your code with "Any CPU" or "x64" and deploy on a Windows 10 64 bits in %ProgramFiles% (not %ProgramFiles(x86)% !) toast notifications will never appear.

However it works in non-64 bits specific folder.

Comment: Nope I'm sorry. I've skip the notification bubble in favor of an internal system using WPF

Comment: I've edited my "answer" to bring a possible fix. Please remove your vote. I didn't have enough reputation to use the comment system, sorry. Blame the forum, not me asking the OP.